# How to using renderToNodeStream in React DOM Server that co-work with Templating Engines?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

`renderToNodeStream` is a method that render React component to Stream in Node.js, It's a good practice to render result Steam other than String to reduce time to first meaningful paint. code like this:

```
const http = require('http')
const React = require('react')
const { renderToNodeStream } = require('react-dom/server')
const { createStore } = require('redux')
const App = require('./App')


http
  .createServer((req, res) => {
    renderToNodeStream(App).pipe(res)
  })
  .listen(3000)
```

but, I want using some template engine like [art-template](https://aui.github.io/art-template/), with extra data shared to client, like store which create by Redux.eg:

```
const http = require('http')
const template = require('art-template')
const React = require('react')
const { renderToString } = require('react-dom/server')
const App = require('./App')

const store = createStore()

http
  .createServer((req, res) => {
    const root = template(__dirname + '/index.art', {
      root: renderToString(App),
      store: store.getState(),
      //... other params that pass
    })
    res.write(root)
    res.end()
  })
  .listen(3000)
```

but it only support render to String instead of Stream. Is there some other way or Template Engine that support render result to Steam? Thanks first. :)